# Best Practices: Interaction between Facebook Login and Symfony2

Tags: facebook, symfony, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I wounder what is the best way to implement a login/registration with facebook in my symfony2 application.

What i want: I want to secure the whole application (except /login). On login page i will provide a facebook login button, like this

```
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

If a user authenticates with facebook, i want to look if there is already an user in the database with this fb-id, then set this user as the actual authenticated symfony user. if user not exist in database, "register" it and write it to database (and set as symfony secure user).

what i already have is this:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '...',
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        var params = new Array();
        params['accessToken']  = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        params['expiresIn']  = response.authResponse.expiresIn;
        params['signedRequest']  = response.authResponse.signedRequest;
        params['userID']  = response.authResponse.userID;
        postToUrl("{{ path('_user_checkfbuser') }}", params);
      }
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));


function postToUrl(path, params, method) {
  method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

  var form = document.createElement("form");
  form.setAttribute("method", method);
  form.setAttribute("action", path);

  for(var key in params) {
    if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
     }
  }

  document.body.appendChild(form);
  form.submit();
  return true;
}
</script>
```

and my controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/user/checkfbuser", name="_user_checkfbuser")
 */
public function checkFBUserAction()
{
    if($this->get("request")->getMethod() == "POST"){
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $accessToken = $request->request->get('accessToken');
        $expiresIn = $request->request->get('expiresIn');
        $signedRequest = $request->request->get('signedRequest');
        $userID = $request->request->get('userID');

        $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('...:User')->findOneBy(
            array('id' => '1')
        );

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'secured_area', $user->getRoles());
        $this->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main',serialize($token));
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_frontend_index'));
    }
    return false;
}
```

What is the usual way to implement such a behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the facebook authentication manually follow the instructions on:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1

You will need to understand what the access token does.

The login flow should be,

1. Initiate oAuth request from Facebook with a redirect uri via a redirect(php)/location assign(javascript)
2. An authentication dialog will popup for user to enter login details (this step will ensure the user knows the username and password of their facebook account).
3. Capture redirect to redirect_uri to symfony action to process
4. Use returned code (not access code) , request_uri and your app secret to request from Facebook an access_token. This step is to ensure the request is indeed from your application (please keep your app secret hidden - do not show in any client side code).
5. If successful, Facebook will return a usable access token to be used for future requests to the Graph API (although it has an expiry window).
6. Use your access token to get email/username data etc to match with Symfony user account.
7. Authenticate user with Symfony like you normally do.

Answer (score 0):

[FosFacebookBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle) is for this purpose. It integrates the [Facebook PHP SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/), and automates the register/login process between facebook and symfony. 
I used it once, but it is a littlebit hard to customize if you need some more advanced logic. In that case I just used the FacebookSdk directly.If you need help with that, tell me:)

Comment: yeah i know the bundle, but i want to use it naturaly and know what happens.

Comment: the thing i need to know is how to check if the user with user_id from facebook is a real user in my database.
as u can see i send the authResponse object via post to my symfony action where i need to process this data and either look for the user entity in database or create a new one.
but how do i use the access token?

Comment: If the userID from the request contains the actual facebook user id, why isn't it enought to save it to a column, and search the DB for that? Why do you need accessToken, expiresIn, signedRequest?

Comment: i dont know, is it enough? i mean, couldnot everybody send a post request to my action-url with some fb-id parameter and get an authenticated user to my app? isnt that kind of a security risk?

i dont really understand the purpose of that accesstoken, so i thought i might miss something in the routine to log in a user in my application via fb-login.

Comment: You are right, but this is why it is safer to use the Fb php sdk, because it uses curl (which makes the authentication request to facebook directly from the server) to authenticate the user, so for the client the whole process it transparent.